# Undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

For my Ruby on Rails website (1.8.7, 2.3.15) I'm trying to pull data from a MySQL table, but I'm running into an "Undefined Method" error. My goal with this code is to display a text list of all locations that fall within a certain latitude and longitudinal range.

**Production.log:**

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass) on line #31 of     app/views/its/map.html.erb:
28: <!-- TestingLocations -->
29: 
30: <ul id="locations">
31: <% for masterlocation in @nearbylocations %>
32:     <li><%= masterlocation.nickname %></a></li>
33: <% end %>
34: </ul>
```

**Map controller:**

```
def map
@its = Its.find(params[:id])
if @its.user_id == current_user.id
@locations = Location.find(:all, :conditions => ["its_id = ?", params[:id]], :order => "order_num asc")
@mapscount = Saved.count(:all, :conditions => ['its_id = ?', params[:id]])
#@date_filter = Date.civil(params[:date_filter].values_at(:year, :month, :day))
#    debugger
respond_to do |format|
format.html # map.html.erb
format.xml  { render :xml => @its }
end
else
redirect_to '/'

@nearbylocations = Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => ["latitude > 25 AND latitude < 30 AND longitude > -75 AND longitude < -70", params[:id]], :order => ['nickname asc'])
end
```

Again, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `@nearbylocations` is `nil` where as it is expecting an `Array`

you can avoid this by using

```
<% for masterlocation in @nearbylocations %>
  <li><%= masterlocation.nickname %></a></li>
<% end if @nearbylocations %>
```

I also notice that you are declared instance variable after redirecting.
Ideally

```
redirect_to '/'
@nearbylocations = Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => ["latitude > 25 AND latitude < 30 AND longitude > -75 AND longitude < -70", params[:id]], :order => ['nickname asc'])
```

should be

```
@nearbylocations = Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => ["latitude > 25 AND latitude < 30 AND longitude > -75 AND longitude < -70", params[:id]], :order => ['nickname asc'])
redirect_to '/'
```

But after redirection you can't use `@nearbylocations` so you have to use either `render` or declare it in redirected method.

Comment: Wow. Each of you guys found something I had done incorrectly. I'm giving @Salil the answer because he was first and had the most thorough response. However, @surase.prasad gave the most concise answer, and ultimately I followed his instructions to get it to work. Only @okliv noticed that my conditions were in error, however. In short, I appreciate all of your help!

My solution:
1) I moved the @nearbylocations line to just below def map

2) I changed it to `@nearbylocations = Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => ["latitude > 25 AND latitude < 30"], :order => ['nickname asc'])`

Answer (score 0):

ur getting a nill error cause ur @nearbylocations isnt getting evaluated since the 'if' condition is  executed and the Masterlocation query is in 'else'. u may move it out of the condition if the @nearbylocation is always needed.

Answer (score 0):

the devil is here

```
:conditions => ["latitude > 25 AND latitude < 30 AND longitude > -75 AND longitude < -70", params[:id]]
```

this query gives nothing

you have @nearbylocations = nil

and than you receive `undefined method` error

what in :conditions doing `params[:id]`? i guess you forgot to delete it or you forgot to add `?` to query in `""`

Comment: thanks so much for your response! Please see my comment above for an update. Again, I appreciate your help!